# XML Error. CodeIgniter XML-RPC

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter class [XML-RPC](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html).

I have **get** function.

```
public function get($request)
{
    $params = $request->output_parameters();
    $userId = (int)$params[0]["UserId"];

    $users = $this->user_model->get($userId);

    if( count($users) > 0 )
    {
        $result = $users[0];
        $response = array($result, 'struct');
        return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->xmlrpc->send_error_message('404', 'Not Found');
    }
}
```

Она позволяет получить информацию о пользователе по его UserId.

**To call a function using a XML-code**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>get</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>UserId</name>
                    <value><int>1</int></value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

The result is a **response**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
    <value>
        <struct>
            <member>
                <name>faultCode</name>
                <value><int>2</int></value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>faultString</name>
                <value><string>The XML data received was either invalid or not in the correct form for XML-RPC. Turn on debugging to examine the XML data further.</string></value>
            </member>
        </struct>
    </value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

What am i doing wrong?